# Error #2025 twice

Tags: actionscript-3

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;


    public class supportForce extends MovieClip
    {
        private var Player1Child:Player1Actual = new Player1Actual();
        private var Player2Child:Player2Actual = new Player2Actual();
        private var GreenLightLeft:Projectile1 = new Projectile1();
        private var GreenLightRight:Projectile2 = new Projectile2();
        private var NeonChild:mcNeonPlayer = new mcNeonPlayer();
        private var _keyDownStatus:Object = {};
        private var defaultSpeed:int = 10;
        private var Player1Lock:Boolean = false;
        private var Player2Lock:Boolean = false;
        private var Player1Left:Boolean = false;
        private var Player2Left:Boolean = true;
        private var greenLightLeft:Boolean = true;
        private var Player1CD:int = 0;
        private var Player1Ready:Boolean = true;
        private var Player1Hit:Boolean = false;
        private var Player1X:int;
        private var Player1Y:int;
        private var NeonX:int;
        private var NeonY:int;
        private var NeonCD:int = 0;
        private var NeonDuration:int = 240;
        private var NeonUse:Boolean = false;
        public function supportForce()
        {
            this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, general);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onDown);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onUp);
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, keyCheck);
            btnStart.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickStart);
            btnAbout.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickAbout);
            btnDust.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickDust);
        }
        private function general(event:Event)
        {
            Player1X = Player1Child.x;
            Player1Y = Player1Child.y;
            NeonX = NeonChild.x;
            NeonY = NeonChild.y;
            GreenLightLeft.x -=  (defaultSpeed * 2);
            GreenLightRight.x +=  (defaultSpeed * 2);
            //status_text = NeonCD;
            if (NeonDuration > 0 && NeonUse == true)
            {
                NeonDuration -=  1;
            }
            else if (NeonDuration == 0 && NeonUse == true)
            {
                NeonUse = false;
                removeChild(NeonChild);
                addChild(Player1Child);
                Player1Child.x = NeonX;
                Player1Child.y = NeonY;
            }
            if (NeonCD > 0)
            {
                NeonCD -=  1;
            }
            trace(NeonCD);
            if (Player1Child.BladeInstance.hitTestObject(Player2Child) && Player1CD <= 0 && Player1Child.BladeInstance.alpha != 0)
            {
                if (Player1Left == true)
                {
                    Player2Child.x -=  defaultSpeed;
                    Player1Hit = true;
                    Player1CD = 8;
                    //trace("G");
                }
                if (Player1Left == false)
                {
                    Player2Child.x +=  defaultSpeed;
                    Player1Hit = true;
                    Player1CD = 8;
                    //trace("G");
                }
            }
            if (Player1Ready == false)
            {
                Player1CD -=  1;
            }
            if (Player1CD <= 0)
            {
                Player1Ready = true;
                Player1CD = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                Player1Ready = false;
            }
            if (Player1Left == true)
            {
                if (Player1Child.x <= (0 + Player1Child.width))
                {
                    Player1Child.x = (0 + Player1Child.width);
                }
                if (Player1Child.x >= 550)
                {
                    Player1Child.x = 550;
                }
                if (Player1Child.y >= 400)
                {
                    Player1Child.y = 400;
                }
                if (Player1Child.y <= (0 + Player1Child.height))
                {
                    Player1Child.y = (0 + Player1Child.height);
                }
            }
            else if (Player1Left == false)
            {
                if (Player1Child.x <= 0)
                {
                    Player1Child.x = 0;
                }
                if (Player1Child.x >= (550 - Player1Child.width))
                {
                    Player1Child.x = (550 - Player1Child.width);
                }
                if (Player1Child.y <= 0)
                {
                    Player1Child.y = 0;
                }
                if (Player1Child.y >= (400 - Player1Child.height))
                {
                    Player1Child.y = (400 - Player1Child.height);
                }
            }
            if (Player2Child.x <= Player2Child.width)
            {
                Player2Child.x = Player2Child.width;
            }
            if (Player2Child.x >= 550)
            {
                Player2Child.x = 550;
            }
            if (Player2Child.y >= (400 - Player2Child.height))
            {
                Player2Child.y = 400 - Player2Child.height;
            }
            if (Player2Child.y <= 0)
            {
                Player2Child.y = 0;
            }
        }
        private function onUp(e:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            _keyDownStatus[e.keyCode] = false;
        }
        private function onDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            _keyDownStatus[e.keyCode] = true;
        }
        private function keyCheck(event:Event)
        {
            if (_keyDownStatus[37])
            {
                if (Player1Left == false)
                {
                    Player1Left = true;
                    Player1Child.rotation +=  180;
                    Player1Child.y += (Player1Child.height - 5);
                    Player1Child.x +=  Player1Child.width;
                }
                Player1Child.x -=  defaultSpeed;
            }
            if (_keyDownStatus[39])
            {
                if (Player1Left == true)
                {
                    Player1Left = false;
                    Player1Child.rotation +=  180;
                    Player1Child.y -= (Player1Child.height - 5);
                    Player1Child.x -=  Player1Child.width;
                }
                Player1Child.x +=  defaultSpeed;
            }
            if (_keyDownStatus[38])
            {
                Player1Child.y -=  defaultSpeed;
            }
            if (_keyDownStatus[40])
            {
                Player1Child.y +=  defaultSpeed;
            }
            if (_keyDownStatus[96] && Player1Ready == true)
            {
                Player1Child.play();
                Player1Ready = false;
            }
            if (_keyDownStatus[97] && NeonCD <= 0)
            {
                removeChild(Player1Child);
                stage.addChild(NeonChild);
                NeonChild.x = Player1X;
                NeonChild.y = Player1Y;
                NeonCD = 480;
                NeonUse = true;
                Player1Lock = false;
            }
            if (_keyDownStatus[65])
            {
                if (Player2Left == false)
                {
                    Player2Left = true;
                    Player2Child.rotation -=  180;
                    Player2Child.y -= (Player2Child.height - 5);
                    Player2Child.x -=  Player2Child.width;
                }
                Player2Child.x -=  defaultSpeed;
            }
            if (_keyDownStatus[68])
            {
                if (Player2Left == true)
                {
                    Player2Left = false;
                    Player2Child.rotation +=  180;
                    Player2Child.y += (Player2Child.height - 5);
                    Player2Child.x +=  Player2Child.width;
                }
                Player2Child.x +=  defaultSpeed;
            }
            if (_keyDownStatus[87])
            {
                Player2Child.y -=  defaultSpeed;
            }
            if (_keyDownStatus[83])
            {
                Player2Child.y +=  defaultSpeed;
            }
            if (_keyDownStatus[90])
            {
                if (Player2Left == true)
                {
                    var GreenLightLeft:Projectile1 = new Projectile1();
                    stage.addChild(GreenLightLeft);
                    GreenLightLeft.x = Player2Child.x;
                    GreenLightLeft.y = Player2Child.y;
                    greenLightLeft = true;
                }
                if (Player2Left == false)
                {
                    var GreenLightRight:Projectile2 = new Projectile2();
                    stage.addChild(GreenLightRight);
                    GreenLightRight.x = (Player2Child.x);
                    GreenLightRight.y = (Player2Child.y - Player2Child.height);
                    greenLightLeft = false;
                }
            }
        }
        private function clickStart(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            gotoAndStop(2);
        }
        private function clickAbout(event:MouseEvent):void
        {

        }
        private function clickDust(event:MouseEvent):void
        {

        }
    }

}
```

It works perfectly when I press <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> (97) but the second time, it gives this error.

```
ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
    at supportForce/keyCheck()
```

So I planned of removeing the `NeonChild` after 10 seconds or 240 frames but it gives this error.

```
ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
    at supportForce/general()
```

If you cannot understand what I am trying to say, this is the link to the actual .fla and .as

[files](https://www.mediafire.com/folder/i93zm31p7513m/A_Game)

Comment: you are trying to remove a child regardless if that child has any parent or if it even exist. You should check those condition before doing anything. Both given answers are plain wrong and faulty btw.

Answer (score 1):

if you dont know parent of displayObject, which you want to remove you can write

```
mc.parent.removeChilte(mc);
```

where mc is movieclip , which you want to delete

Comment: I tried that but it shows the error #1119 Access of possibly undefined property parent through a reference with static type Class.

Comment: are you sure that parent type is DisplayObject?

Comment: Yes thank you but I found out a solution. Thanks anyways as the solution is partly from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead

```
this.parent.removeChild(mc);
```

where mc is the MovieClip.